# Can CardView be achieved from a recycler view?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to `RecyclerView` and `CardView`. After reading their documentation and some code samples, I didn't understand one thing (`CardView` can be achived by designing `RecyclerView` rows).

To clarify: In order to make a recycler view we make a layout (row layout) that contains all the views we want to represent in a row (Images , texts, ...). In this layout, we can put views in any position and any order. I mean everything that we get in cardview can be achieved right here. So why we use a cardview?

Comment: you can make the rows like gmail app without cardview and you make it with cardview just depend on your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RecyclerView** is basically an advance **ListView**.

It is used to display your data in a list view. At its simplest , it uses a built in list file, which shows only single column of data.

[image: ListView]

If you want to change the **DISPLAY** of your **LIST** like this

[image: cardview]

Then you would go about , creating CardView widget.
BTW, RecyclerView is very flexible and CardView is it's best companion to show your data in a very Efficient manner.

Comment: then you mean instead of making a layout for roww in recycler view its better to use cardview as a layout for my rows?

Comment: yes. basically , when you create list_item_view file, it should have card view to show gorgeous  ui

Answer (score 1):

`CardView` is a `ViewGroup` that can host all the views of each of your `RecyclerView` items.
 Of course you can create a `RecyclerView` without a `CardView` and just use a simple layout. 
What a `CardView` has to offer is easy customization so to achieve a nice UI.  
Just by using 2 of its atributes:

```
app:cardElevation="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
```

you can do what you would achieve by creating nasty drawables to assign as backgroud to layouts.
These attributes are not the only ones. 
You can experiment with a `CardView` so to get the desired result.